# 409 HTTP error in JFrog Artifactory's system logs

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

I manually deploy(click button on web) FGE-0.3.zip to `lib-release` without a pom file. For some reason I check `Suppress POM Consistency Checks` of a `lib-snapshots`, and after that there are a lot of error messages in my system logs:

> Sending HTTP error code 409: The repository 'lib-snapshots' rejected the artifact 'lib-snapshots:com/tools/FGE/0.3/FGE-0.3.pom' due to its snapshot/release handling policy

`FGE` is actually in a `lib-release`, why is this happen?

Comment: Here is a similar question, but I still didn't figure out: https://sourceforge.net/p/artifactory/mailman/message/29442960/

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably trying to deploy a `release` *artifact* to a repository that you [configured](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-AdditionalBasicSettings) not to handle releases - the *name* of the repository by itself has no bearing on it's behavior so you probably mixed something up.

Repositories in Artifactory can handle `release` or `snapshot` artifacts or both - which artifact is considered `release` or `snapshot` is determined by the repository's [layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) (The folder and file [integration revision](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts#RepositoryLayouts-ModuleFields) parts in it specifically).

POM consistency checks are there to validate the *path* you deployed a `pom` file to adheres to it's `GAV` coordinates - the error you are seeing is because of the `handle release` \ `handle snapshot` configuration.